# Start colorbox popup after loading automatically

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I would like to open automatically the colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) if the site was loaded. It should open the first link of a give a href-list.

html:

```
<a class="cb cboxElement" rel="aktuelles" href="aktuelles.php?id=38">
<a class="cb cboxElement" rel="aktuelles" href="aktuelles.php?id=40">
<a class="cb cboxElement" rel="aktuelles" href="aktuelles.php?id=39">
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.cb").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:760, innerHeight:640});
});
```

Can anybody help me?

thanks + best regards
thomas

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with your current solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add open property to the colorbox config object :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.cb").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:760, innerHeight:640, open: true});
});
```